# Efficient alternative for "ismember" function for arrays - MATLAB

Tags: arrays, performance, matlab, comparison, cell-array

if `A` is a series of points coordinate in 2D, for example:

```
>> A = [1 2; 3 4; 5 6; 7 8; 9 0];
A =
     1     2
     3     4
     5     6
     7     8
     9     0
```

and `B` contained two cells which each cell is a portion of 'A' and represented just with `x` values (first column), means:

```
>> B = {[3; 7];[5]}
B =
     [2x1 double]
     [     5    ]
```

I am looking for a solution to search `B` cells into `A` and give the coordinates of those points.

This is my code which is very slow for a large set of data:

```
C = cell (length(B) ,1)

for i = 1 : length(B)
     C{i} = A(ismember(A(:,1),B{i},'rows'),:);
end
```

`C` is the right answer and include 2 cells which are coordinates of each cell of `B`:

```
C = 
    [2x2 double]
    [1x2 double]

>> C{1}
ans =
     3     4
     7     8
```

and

```
>> C{2}
ans =
     5     6
```

Again, although `C` is the correct answer, I am looking for a more efficient solution. Probably `cellfun`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `'rows'` with `ismember` there. So, you can just do -

```
for k = 1 : numel(B)
    C{i}=A(ismember(A(:,1),B{k}),:);
end
```

Not sure if that would speedup your solution though.

---

As a second approach and this could be faster (not tested though), you can use `bsxfun` -

```
for k = 1 : numel(B)
    C{k} = A(any(bsxfun(@eq,A(:,1),B{k}.'),2),:);
end
```

Of course, before using either of the approaches, do `pre-allocate` with -

```
C = cell (numel(B) ,1)
```

Comment: the second approach looks great. Thanks budy

Comment: @Iman Awesomeness! Any runtime comparison results that you could gather?

Comment: I optimized many things in my code today, then it is a bit hard to say the effect of this function on such a real data (>two million points!) separately.

However, I ran on the above `A` and `B` and it shows your second approach is 72.5% faster than mine. Good job!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the `cellfun` version, although I doubt it is any faster than the loop (perhaps even slightly slower):

```
>> C = cellfun(@(b) A(ismember(A(:,1),b),:), B, 'Uniform',false)
C = 
    [2x2 double]
    [1x2 double]

>> C{:}
ans =
     3     4
     7     8
ans =
     5     6
```

Comment: You're right. It makes it slower but still a nice try . Thanks